# perl5140delta localized tied variables

Tags: perl, documentation, tie

[perl5140delta](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.14.0/pod/perldelta.pod#Localised_tied_hashes_and_arrays_are_no_longed_tied) says that localized tied variables are no long tied. This change was implemented in [5.13.1](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perl5131delta) but reverted in [5.13.2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perl5132delta). Is this back in 5.14 (from my testing it does not appear to be) or is the delta for 5.14.0 incorrect?

I care because I believe this would break [`File::chdir`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3achdir) which I use regularly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The perldelta says that localized tied "hashes and arrays" are no longer tied.  Scalars are unaffected.

The doc you linked, perl5132delta says:

```
localised tied scalars are tied again.

The change in behaviour in 5.13.1 of localising tied scalar values has been reverted to the existing 5.12.0 and earlier behaviour (the change for arrays and hashes remains).
```

The really useful thing I have to say is that you can check your favorite module's status on many versions of Perl using the CPAN Testers service.

Check out the report for [File::chdir 0.1004](http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/F/File-chdir.html#File-chdir-0.1004).  It passes all of the 5.14 RC tests on different platforms.  According to CPANTS you are in good shape.

Of course you could download and build a test version of 5.14 and try it yourself, just to be sure.

Comment: Of course, you are correct. I saw what I expected to see, not what was actually there. Thanks!